# How can I map a service in Google Cloud Servers?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, ping, nslookup

I am in the process of making our application into smaller services. I add the new services on a back end server (i.e. not accessible to public) and then make entries in /etc/hosts file of our web servers. Sample entry

```
10.160.x.xx newservice.mydomain.com
```

This approach works. But if I test the service from the web server, I see that ping works, not nslookup. So `ping newservice.mydomain.com` is successful, not `nslookup newservice.mydomain.com`
Why is it so? How can I make nslookup also work?

Answer (score 1):

`nslookup` asks the DNS servers, and they have no knowledge of you local `hosts` file, so they won't resolve the entries contained within it. If you want your `hosts` file to be accessible via DNS lookups, you have to use a DNS server which has knowledge about it (for example, `systemd-resolved` can be configured to parse the file).

However, using a `hosts` entry seems redundant here, as each compute engine instance can be resolved using the default Google cloud DNS server (`169.254.169.254`). The name of each compute engine is `[INSTANCE_NAME].[ZONE].c.[PROJECT_ID].internal` ([more info about the internal DNS is available here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns)), so you should be able to access your servers by that name.